# Can I Upgrade From 32-Bit to 64-Bit?

Tags: upgrade, 64-bit, 32-bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I switch a 32-bit installation to a 64-bit one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one)

I have a 64-bit processor (Intel i3 second gen), and when I installed Ubuntu I went with the 32-bit version because I was just testing it, but now I see it is a lot better than Win7 and want to upgrade to the 64-bit version.  Is there any way to do this without reinstalling?  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Have a look at:http://askubuntu.com/q/81824/58990

Comment: To clarify, [my answer (which the OP accepted)](http://askubuntu.com/a/81838/22949) to [the question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one) @ignite has commented about is **mostly theoretical**. We may close this as a duplicate of that question, but please don't be fooled: the answer to "Can I upgrade from 32-bit to 64-bit" is **almost certainly not**.

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to "upgrade" your current installation of Ubuntu.
You would need to reinstall.
But you do not need to format the whole drive.

If you have done a /home partition, you can keep it, with all your files.