# I want to change from 64 bit Ubuntu 12.10 to 32 bit

Tags: installation, 64-bit, 32-bit, reinstalling

I had installed Ubuntu 12.10 amd64 Desktop on my laptop, but I realized my laptop's hardware is not meant for 64 bit Ubuntu. (I also have Windows 7 installed in another partion)

**Is there any way to convert to a 32 bit Ubuntu?**

**EDIT:**
I have a single core processor ( I don't even think its a 64 bit one)

Comment: If you are using 64-bit already, then there's no reason to move to 32-bit in my opinion. Your hardware is compatible, apparently. Your statement about "my laptop's hardware is not meant for 64 bit Ubuntu" seems invalid for this reason.

Comment: If 64bit Ubuntu installed at all, your hardware is up to it. It wouldn't even let you install if it weren't.

Comment: See very similar question: [How can I switch a 32-bit installation to a 64-bit one?](http://askubuntu.com/q/81824/88802) - While it's the other way around it shows the reasons for why it is **very hard**.

Comment: Your PC must be 64-bit capable if its installed otherwise it would not have installed. If you really want to change to 32-bit the easiest way is Backup then Install the 32-bit version telling it to replace the existing one.  Finally restore your data from the backup.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**I've figured it out.**

First I had to uninstall Ubuntu and restoring to Windows 7: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LSYGkSptSy4

Then after deleting the partion where Ubuntu was installed I inserted my Ubuntu 12.10 i386 disc and installed it on the same old partion.

Comment: How does this answer your question? You're describing a full reinstall while you were asking for a way to convert it.

Comment: Well, there's no way to change the OS architecture, (I believe), but then there is reinstalling the whole OS, but anyways I found what I wanted and it worked!