# Which Google Chrome version should I install for my system?

Tags: installation, google-chrome

The computer is a Toshiba Satellite system, and it was left here by an old roommate who destroyed the Windows 7 operating system. He repaired it by installing Ubuntu on it. We are in desperate need of another computer, but for now I'm figuring out how to install Chrome on this installation.

Further system information:

- Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS
- Memory: 2.7 GB
- Processor: AMD Turion(tm)II P540 Dual Core Processor
- Graphics: Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x300)
- OS type: 32-bit
- Disk: 154.6 GB.

when trying to install Google Chrome I was asked what download package to choose:

- 32 bit deb (for Debian/Ubuntu
- 64 bit deb (for Debian/Ubuntu)
- 32 bit rpm (for Fedora/openSUSE)
- 64 bit rpm (for Fedora/openSUSE)

So Which one do I choose? I know that I have a 64 bit computer, and Ubuntu says that my OS type is a 32 bit.

Also, is there any way to upgrade to where it recognizes that it is a 64 bit system?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please keep it to one question per post. For your second one at the bottom of your post, see: [How can I switch a 32-bit installation to a 64-bit one?](http://askubuntu.com/q/81824/88802)

Answer (score 2):

For your current OS you can go for the 32 bit version without a problem. Just choose the proper option from the choices and after downloading the .deb package, run it by opening (maybe double click is needed), after which the Software Center Will appear allowing you to install the latest Google Chrome.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Although your computer is capable of running a 64 bit OS it seems someone installed a 32 bit OS. This will not cause any problems, you just might not get optimal performance. So it looks like you would want to install "32 bit Deb".

However, if you look in the Software Store you can download Chromium browser. It is almost identical to Chrome and the install process is simpler. Here's the direct link to Chromium in Software Centre: [chromium-browser [image: Install chromium-browser]](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/chromium-browser)

Comment: We must say that you may experience some kind of problems with Chromium, let's mention the Flash Player issues which Chrome won't observe by having the Flash Player embedded and Chrome is also having a PDF viewer embedded which makes easier to browse almost any website. Anyway there are solutions for everything. :) Thank you for pointing to Chromium.

Comment: Chromium in the Software Center has **not** been updated for several months. Take a look at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1183086 for the possible implications.

Comment: Good news: Version 28.0.1500.52 Ubuntu 13.04 (28.0.1500.52-0ubuntu1.13.04.2) is available from the Software Center!