# What is the easiest way to fix a mixup of 32-bit and 64-bit?

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit

I have a machine which I have accidentally install 32-bit 12.04 LTS on.

(Yes, accidentally. I can't recall how I managed that.)

What is the easiest way to fix this? Mucking about with the kernel files or axing it with a reinstall?

Is it possible and safe to have a dual boot of 32 and 64-bit 12.04 LTS?

Comment: @chaskes Not really, I am asking which is easier.

Comment: The other q/a covers which is easier. In fact, it's the same answer linked below. I still see it as a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the easiest way to fix this? Mucking about with the kernel files or axing it with a reinstall?

Just reinstall. The way to fix it would be [immensely time consuming and complex](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one).

> Is it possible and safe to have a dual boot of 32 and 64-bit 12.04 LTS?

As long as you have a 64-bit CPU, there will be no conflict between dual-booting. The two installations will be completely isolated from each other and will perform independently.