# Switched from 32 to 64bit kernel. How to install 64bit packages?

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit, multiarch

I followed this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one#answer-152798) and installed 64bit version of kernel.
`uname -m` print `x86_64`, so it's working.

When tried to install 64bit Chrome, Software Center complained about `libcups:amd64`. Tried to install it manuelly, but I got

```
sudo apt-get install libcups2:amd64
.....
.....
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
kde-runtime : Depends: libsmbclient (>= 2:4.0.3+dfsg1) but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: kubuntu-debug-installer but it is not going to be installed
libcups2:amd64 : Depends: libgssapi-krb5-2:amd64 (>= 1.10+dfsg~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
```

Shouldn't this just work with multiarch? If not, how to install 64bit packages?