# How can I update ubuntu from 32bit to 64bit?

Tags: updates, 64-bit, android

I am a android developer, I recently installed ubuntu in my another desktop that is 32 bit.

I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS

When I am going to make a virtual android device through eclipse+android sdk, it's not running. It's saying me to update into 64bit.

Can anyone please give me a solution, how can I run it or update to 64bit from 32bit.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: If would advice to re-install. If you do not want to see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it in simple way. What I would do is to save the content of `/home` and the `/etc`, afterwards make a list of installed packages with:

```
dpkg --get-selections > ~/Package.list
sudo cp -R /etc/apt/sources.list* ~/
sudo apt-key exportall > ~/Repo.keys
```

After that save somewhere the created files, and reinstall your Ubuntu choosing the 64bit version. When finished with basic install, copy back the `/home` and `/etc`, and restore the packages you had before with:

```
sudo apt-key add ~/Repo.keys
sudo cp -R ~/sources.list* /etc/apt/
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install dselect
sudo dpkg --set-selections < ~/Package.list
sudo apt-get dselect-upgrade -y
```

Ofcourse adjust the paths of your backed up files.

Comment: Well, I'm trying to copy the the content of /home and the /etc to another drive but it's won't copying. It's saying me permission denied.

Comment: Try copying with the rsync command and run it as root using sudo.  That way you are allowed to access all files.  Do not use the root user more than necessary, as that is a security threat to your system.  When you reinstall later, make a separate partition for /home, as that will make it easier to reinstall and backup your data.

Comment: can you please know me, how can I use terminal for copying these files ?
Can you please send me step by step lesson for upgrading into 64bit ubuntu.