# Downgrading 64bit to 32bit

Tags: system-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit, downgrade

Is it possible to downgrade from 14.04.1 64-bit to 32-bit as an old PC is having real trouble running 64-bit.

Comment: Check this http://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one?lq=1

Answer (score 0):

32bit and 64bit are classed as different CPU architecture. You will have to perform a clean install.

However if you just want to run 32bit programs you can install ia32-libs-multiarch to add 32bit support to the 64bit OS

> sudo apt-get install ia32-libs-multiarch