# update from 32bits to 64bits ubuntu mate 15.04

Tags: updates, 15.04

Has anyone know how to upgrade from 32bits to 64bits ubuntu mate without reinstalling again?? I try to find anywhere on google search and cant find any solution.  I have 32bits Ubuntu mate 15.04 and want to update to 64bits ubuntu mate without have to reinstall whole thing!
Any ideas?﻿

Comment: Backup and reinstall 64bit.

Comment: Here is a how to: http://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one (=dupe) BUT I agree with @xangua