# How can I upgrade to ubuntu 16.04 64 bit from ubuntu 14.04 32 bit?

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, 16.04

I am currently using ubuntu version 14.04, but I want to upgrade to 16.04 without reinstalling ubuntu. So can anyone help me out.

Comment: Possible, but strongly unadviceable for beginners!!

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade from 14.04 32 bit to 16.04 64 bit, but not easily and not well. The best solution for you would probably be to back everything up and do a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 64 bit.

However, if you want to try it anyways, do all the steps in the answer to this question.

[How can I switch a 32-bit installation to a 64-bit one?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one)

Then in a terminal run the command below.

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```