# Ubuntu 18.04 upgrade to 20.04 throws i386 error BUT system says it's already x86_64

Tags: server, package-management, upgrade, 32-bit

running do-release-upgrade on Ubuntu 18.04.x server throws:

Sorry, no more upgrades for this system

There will not be any further Ubuntu releases for this system's
'i386' architecture.

Updates for Ubuntu 18.04 will continue until April 2023.

but running uname -r results in 5.8.3-x86_64-linode137
and running uname -m results in x86_64

Does this mean that the system is 64 bit, but something else is 32 bit and preventing the upgrade? This server has been updated through several lts versions of Ubuntu, so there are probably 32 bit versions of packages in there, so perhaps these are the 'i386 architecture' causing the problem? Any known workarounds to this, or is this just a reinstall from scratch situation... or is there a magical command to upgrade all packages to 64 versions if they are 32 versions on a 64 system?

Comment: My opinion only, but after several upgrades do think think it would be time to clean out system and do a clean install.  Back up first.

Comment: Just curious: what are the outputs of `dpkg --print-architecture` and `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures`?

Comment: dpkg --print-architecture gives i386 and dpkg --print-foreign-architectures returns nothing

Comment: never tried I made a clean install 64bit https://askubuntu.com/questions/81824/how-can-i-switch-a-32-bit-installation-to-a-64-bit-one