# Can ubuntu 64 bit run ubuntu 32 application?

Tags: 12.04, 64-bit, 32-bit

Can ubuntu 64 bit run ubuntu 32 application?

Now all our pcs and laptop are i7, 16GB memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can. The only thing you will start seeing is that any 32 Bit app will end with **":386"**. Here is an image to give you an idea:

[image]

As you can see, you ca try to install `skype` using the 32 bit version `skype:i386`). Same goes for pidgin and any other app that has a 32 bit version in a 64 bit system. Most apps do. If the 64 bit version is not available, they will most likely fallback to the 32 bit one.

Comment: I knew mac and windows can run 32 bit app on 64 bit os.  But why in ubuntu office website, they are still recommend 32 bit os. Is it not stable?   I also notice apple start to sell their 64 bit os 10 years ago.

Comment: @王子1986 It's just a recommendation based on the amount of users using 32 bit versus 64 bit. I can say from experience when I moved to 64 bit in 12.10 that most bigger problems with 64 bit were gone.  I tested long before 64 bit and still have issues as mentioned here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/19803/for-better-performance-should-i-install-32-bit-or-64-bit/19806#19806 but usign 12.10 and most recently, testing out the 13.04 development version I can surely say that it is very stable.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, assuming the requisite 32-bit dependencies of the application are installed. There are some applications which are 32-bit only, but installable and usable on 64-bit Ubuntu, from the partner repository.

You can't mix architectures within the same process though, so a 32-bit program can't load 64-bit shared libraries, or vice versa.