# Install 64-bit OS on an old PC?

Tags: 64-bit

Before downloading, there is an option to choose 32 bit or 64 bit, but It says only newer PC's. Can I still install this OS on my old 64 bit PC?

Comment: What is the make/model of your older PC? The 64-bit versions run on anything that supports the x64 architecture (also known as x86-64 or amd64). The older IA-64 (Intel Itanium) is a different architecture and is not instruction-set compatible. As long as your PC has the right chipset, it'll work - 'newer' is a relative term.

Comment: @roger Probably. If your old 64-bit PC doesn't have much RAM, the 32-bit version might perform better. See [What are the system requirements for each flavor of Ubuntu Desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/q/333795) to check to make sure your system meets the system requirements in all ways. (We may close this as a duplicate of that.) You'll likely want the 64-bit version, but see [What is the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit and which should I choose?](http://askubuntu.com/q/7034), and [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/19803). If you want a lighter system, see [this](http://askubuntu.com/q/206407).

Answer (score 1):

Strange question. Yes, of course, you *can* install 64-bit Ubuntu to 64-bit PC (if it meets other requirements, of course). And if you think it is old this does not mean that it is really old. The *newer* word in this case means that 64-bit architecture is slightly younger than 32-bit, that's all.

Other Requirements:

- AMD64 CPU
- 1 GB RAM
- 5.4 GB Free Space on hard drive
- (Recommended) Internet connection