# Ubuntu 32-bit or 64-bit for AMD E1-1200 processor

Tags: ati, 64-bit

I have my laptop AMD E1-1200 with 1.4GHz but 4GB RAM with a AMD Radeon 7310 HD graphics card. I was trying to move to using Linux and someone advised me to install Ubuntu, but what should I do? Should I download Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit or 64-bit for this laptop? And what's the difference?

Comment: just asking about the best for this E1-1200 because i read many answers but i need a recommendation for this one .. thank u after edit .. i'll try 64-bit

Comment: Regarding a specific recommendation [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/19803/for-better-performance-should-i-install-32-bit-or-64-bit/19806#19806) by Luis Alvarado is also worth reading. Skip to the end of the answer for the recommendation part.