# How do I know my system is broken after chown -R root usr/bin?

Tags: 12.04, sudo, root, chown

This question is related to another question -- "[Can't access any functions after chown command.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19717/cant-access-any-functions-after-chown-command/)" -- but I think it may be worthy of an independent question.  My question is: how do I know that my system is messed up and that I should probably re-install?  I already know that I made a huge stupid mistake, as is discussed on related question :)  Here's what I did:

I wanted to learn a little about mysql.  I know very little about databases and as you can tell from what I did, I know very little about linux.  I was following instructions on [this mysql tutorial page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/unix-postinstallation.html), accidentally ran the command:

```
/usr/bin$ sudo chown -R root .
```

After doing this, I realized my recklessness and naivete (all criticisms duly received) by getting the following error trying to run sudo:

```
sudo: must be setuid root
```

Besides enjoying using linux, part of my reason for using it is to gain experience, and thus, this mistake was not a total disaster.  All my data are in the cloud, so it will just be the several hours of reinstalling everything that will cost me.  But before I reinstall, I want to know how I can tell that my system is messed up.  I was able to fix the "sudo problem" with the following helpful article: http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/fixsudo

I booted in recovery mode (by pressing shift during boot), I chose "Drop to root shell prompt," and then I think I ran the following commands:

```
mount -o rw/remount /
sudo chown root:root /usr/bin/sudo
sudo chmod 4755 /usr/bin/sudo
```

(The last two commands based on [this askbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/139182/56403).)

After doing so and rebooting, sudo now "works" again, and I don't notice obvious problems with my system.  However, as I have learned, my initial mistake changed ownership on the entire usr/bin directory and subdirectories.  From what I hear, the best way to fix this is to reinstall the system and packages.  But my question is: what kind of diagnostics can I do to know that my system is messed up from the ownership changes?  So far things seem to work fine, such as: chromium, python, gedit, and apt-get.  If I had made a different bone-headed mistake, I may not know I have a problem, so I am curious about some kind of diagnostic things I could check and what my primary motivation for reinstalling ubuntu would be.  I am currently using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. Thank you!